# When the non-clustered index is created on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Is that right after I run the index creation command? When the table's data is deleted, is the index created again right after the data is inserted again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index is created when you issue a `CREATE INDEX` command.

And the index is **maintained**, e.g. inserting and deleting data will **automatically update** the index "on the fly" - no specific re-creation needed.

That's why having **too many indices** on a table can negatively affect your performance - every insert, update or delete will have to maintain all the indices that are present on the table - and that does take a little bit of time for each index.

Comment: So the index is effective right after it is created? what if a table contains 1000000 rows, how long it takes to create those index normally? what if I run a query right i created index, will this query be improved right away?

Comment: @Zhongmin: the index is "active" as soon as it's fully created, yes. Depending on the complexity and the size of your table, this can take some time - but there's just too many variables in play for any guess, here - you just need to run this and measure.